# What are these small things on my laundry room wall?

Tags: laundry

I'd like to install a floating shelf here. I guess I should remove these. But I want to understand what these small things are and make sure I won't regret removing them.

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone had something there before and did bad job fixing wall back.  Big one looks like a broken face of drywall anchor for screw.

Comment: It would help if you replaced the picture with one that has something in the image for scale, like a finger or coin or something...

Comment: Good point. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are between 1/4" and 3/8" in diameter, they're old plastic drywall anchors.

[image]

If your shelf covers them, don't worry at all. If they're visible, slice the flange off with a knife or chisel, push the remaining plastic into the wall cavity and spackle to fix.

If nothing else, these will tell you where your stud isn't. (And you'll really need to know that to get a secure floating shelf up.)

Comment: Add a screw and a photo frame for a really lazy way of hiding the holes.